# Is There a World That Exactly Mimics Our Own?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, existentialism

**If** parallel universes do indeed exist and if we are just viewing one tiny part of reality, is it possible that in an alternate universe there would appear an exact replica of our world?

Note: I understand this question is extremely hypothetical and it can't be answered with full confidence because of the complexity in dealing with alternate universes. But what I am trying to ask is what are the predominant theories regarding the existence of a mirrored universe (if any).

Comment: I've made an edit. You may roll this back or continue editing. You can see the versions by clicking "edited" above my image. I added a philosophy-of-science tag because I think there is a no-go theorem that might prevent exact replication. Welcome to this SE.

Comment: The answer to a non-specific "is it possible?" is always "anything is possible", such speculations are not SE question material. A much better source for generic inquiries of this sort are online encyclopedias, like [Wikipedia's Multiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse), and other sites found by googling. If you wish to ask something more specific about theories of multiple universes the more suitable place would be Physics SE, and it would have to be *much* more specific.

Comment: I’m not sure if you can see this since it was closed, but [I asked a similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/421665/123726) on Physics SE, and it wasn’t very popular. Maybe I should ask it here.

Comment: Leibniz claims (quite convincingly) that a world that would mimick our world would be just that, our world. See "Cosmic Coincidences: Another Explanation" by Helier Robinson.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in fact it's inevitable, by current thinking. https://www.universetoday.com/48619/a-universe-of-10-dimensions/

Although you have to distinguish between the 'uncollapsed wavefunction' of all possible universes with given starting conditions, and a set of observables like our actual universe. It isn't really correct to say our universe splits, that would involve infinite multiplying of energy. It is one outcome of a probability superposition that forms a larger space.

It is unlikely that connections could be made between outcomes, anymore than between two points in space or time (wormholes), although there are a huge amount of unknowns.

Comment: I don't see where in the cited link it says that it is "inevitable" that there exists a world that "exactly mimics our own". The article does mention all possible universes. In those possible universes (even in a MWI) are there universes that *exactly mimic our own*?

Comment: @Frank Hubeny The dimensions represent spacesbof increasing orders of possibility, up to and including allbpossible laws of physics and starting conditions. In this model all the possible pasts and futures of now are layers within this hierarchy of all pissibilities. Admittedly the ontic ststus is sketchy, but the possibilities have real consequences

Comment: Couldn't be more wrong. Multiverse theories rely on statistical properties. Measure zero events in infinite probability spaces allow for plenty of exceptions to probabilistic certainties. There's a lot of bad and muddled thinking around these issues in the literature and certainly on the Internet.